# Does order of html meta tags matter?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an asp.net web form with a head section like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Web application</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="resources/material.min.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="resources/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="resources/favicon.ico" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/material.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>
</head>
```

The application won't work in Internet Explorer compatibility mode, which unfortunately our firm enables in IE by default. Normally I fix this by adding the meta tag above, but for some reason this isn't working on this page. If I move the meta tag to the top of the `<head>` section, before the style sheets, it does work. So my question is this: is there a reason the order matters? I'm baffled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, order matters. The browser procedurally processes HTML. If the `meta` tag is first, Internet Explorer knows to use Compatibility Mode almost as soon as it starts parsing the document. Otherwise, it's already started parsing and processed everything else - your CSS, JavaScript, *not* in Compatibility Mode.

Comment: And the encoding, which is missing, should be at the top for the same reason. In fact w3c validation will raise an error if encoding is too far from the top.